# Largest stable object in "daily" orbit

Tags: moons, day-night

I am considering a world with a very long light/dark cycle.

However, I would like some natural method of measuring out a "day-like" period of time.

Could an object with an orbital period of around 24 hours be large enough to show up as a "moon"?  I'd like it to be large enough to pass in front of the sun and cause at least a partial eclipse every pass.

If an earth-size planet makes this too problematical, a larger planet may work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple three-body system like you describe (star much larger than planet, planet much larger than moon, moon much closer to planet than star), there's no real stability issue.  The only limiting factor is that you can't place the smaller body closer than the [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit); for typical planetary compositions, this is about 2.4 times the radius of the larger body.

A 24-hour orbit around an Earth-like planet occurs at a center-to-center distance of about 42,000 km, well above the 15,500 km Roche limit.  A moon with a diameter of 380 km at that altitude would appear the same size as Earth's moon, and have the same eclipse potential.